# Typescript - Convert "object with promises as properties"-Type to "object with resolved promise values as properties"-Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, typing

Is this possible in Typescript?

I want to turn e.g. something like this:

```
interface IPromiseObject {
    promiseA: Promise<number>;
    promiseB: Promise<string>;
}
```

Into this:

```
interface IResolvedPromiseObject {
    promiseA: number;
    promiseB: string;
}
```

I want to use it to resolve an object with promises as values, but still stay type safe. In this example, I need to convert `IPromiseObject` to an object with the same keys but the values resolved so that I can use it as return type.

```
export async function resolveAllObject<IPromiseObject>( promiseObject: IPromiseObject ): Promise<???> {
    const resolvedPromiseObject = {};
    for ( const key in promiseObject ) {
        const value = await promiseObject[ key ];        
        Object.assign( resolvedPromiseObject, { [ key ]: value } );
    }
    return resolvedPromiseObject;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map over the properties and use the `Awaited` utility type to extract the type inside the Promise.

```
type AwaitedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>
}
```

Usage:

```
interface IPromiseObject {
  promiseA: Promise<number>;
  promiseB: Promise<string>;
}

type AwaitedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>
}

type IResolvedPromiseObject = AwaitedObject<IPromiseObject>
// type IResolvedPromiseObject = {
//    promiseA: number;
//    promiseB: string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=60&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsC2wDOEA8gEYBWECYyA3gFDLIAO2ehAggFzKa4EQAeEAFccJaAD4A3A2at%20AIW682g-GCigA5tLoBfOnTABPJinYB3OMEgATUhSoCAKhOQBeWrIDaAaWSgyADWEMZYMMjOALrcltZ2Ln5REvqGJmZoAEoQ%20FgANgBuELYq-A6U1J5xNsXlThjyhHVgEkA)